# Find the volume of the region contained above $z=1$ and below $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=4$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Why doesn't this work?

> Find the volume of the region contained above $z=1$ and below $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=4$

going to cylindrical this should be easy. $z=(4-r^{2})^{\frac {1}{2}}$ and $z=1$
Clearly $z=1$ yields  $x^{2}+y^{2}=3 \to r=(3)^{\frac {1}{2}}$

$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{0}_{(3)^{\frac {1}{2}}} [(4-r^{2})^{\frac {1}{2}} -1] \, r\,dr\,d\theta$$

$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\left[-\frac {1}{3} (4-r^{2})^{\frac {3}{2}}-\frac{r^{2}}{2}\right]\Bigg|^{0}_{(3)^{\frac {1}{2}}} d\theta$$

$$-\frac{8}{3}-\left[-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{3}{2}\right] \to -\frac{16}{6} +\frac{11}{6} \to -\frac{5}{6} \to -\frac{5\pi}{3}$$

I don't get why the bound isn't supposed to be $\int^{0}_{(3)^{\frac {1}{2}}}$ - why is it $\int^{(3)^{\frac {1}{2}}}_{0}?$ Clearly when I start integrating, my radius is root 3 and it reduces to 0?

Comment: +1 for showing your progress and thoughts about the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radius starts at the inner bound (the $z$-axis, or $r=0$, in this case) and works outward (to $r=3^{\frac12}$, in this case). Just like $z$ goes from bottom to top, and $\theta$ works its way counterclockwise.

Comment: i think i understand u always layout r from top to bottom if say i was lazy and used a change of variables( the true kind) would this come out automatically? or would it just crud out a negative sign and the bound as i have written it?

Comment: It *is* sensitive to order, but the $r$ "axis" starts at the $z$-axis and works its way outward from there. If you write it in your order, it would indeed bring out a $-$ sign.

Comment: but when you do a true change of variables r doesn't have any idea who or what z is doing just cause i label it r doesnt make its bound go this way or that when i do a true change of variables? i think ill try it im sure it ends up upside down but a -r comes out instead of an r in the change of variables.

Comment: That's true, so long as our bounds on $r$ are independent of $z$, which they are not in this case.

Comment: Put another way, for every point $(z,r,\theta)$ in the solid, we have $$0\le r\le\sqrt{4-z^2}.$$ If we integrate first with respect to $z$ (as you did), then intuitively we collapse this solid down to its "shadow" on the $r,\theta$ plane to perform the next integration. Namely, the "shadow" consists of the points $(r,\theta)$ such that $$0\le r\le\sqrt 3$$

Comment: It ultimately comes down to the definition of the change of variables. In particular, $(x,y,z)$ is converted to $(z,r,\theta)$ by $$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ and $$\theta=\begin{cases}0 & x=y=0\\\sin^{-1}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\pi & x<0\\\sin^{-1}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle{\int _0^{2\pi }\int _0^{\sqrt{3}}\int _1^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}rdzdrd\theta} $$
$$\displaystyle{2\pi \int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \left(r\sqrt{4-r^2}-r\right) \, dr} $$

The first part you solve it by changing variables:

$$u=4-r^2   \qquad du=-2rdr    \qquad    \frac{-du}{2}=rdr$$

After solving that, the volume is $\frac{5\pi}{3}$

There are 2 ways to solve the problem using cylindrical coordenates

$$0 < \theta <2\pi$$
$$0 < r < \sqrt{3} $$
$$ 1 < z < \sqrt{4-r^2} $$

or

$$0 < \theta <2\pi$$
$$1 < z < 2 $$
$$ 0 < r < \sqrt{4-z^2} $$

r will always go from the inside to the outside, z from de first plane it intersects to the other, and $\theta$ will spin totally in this case

Comment: im not using spherical cords i did in cylindrical.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Here is a cute picture of the question.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Here I have used your image!